# Azure Private Offer ARM template failure

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-marketplace

I'm getting the below error during validation when trying to deploy an ARM template via private offer (cleansed):

{"code":"MarketplacePurchaseEligibilityFailed","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Offer with PublisherId: 'PUBLISHER', OfferId: 'OFFER' cannot be purchased due to validation errors. For more information see details. Correlation Id: 'ID' Sku 'SKU' of offer 'OFFER' by publisher 'PUBLISHER' is not available to you for deployment per the policy set by your IT Admin.

I went through powershell and accepted the terms but still having the issue. Microsoft's responses so far are based on the browser. I've tried in Firefox, Chrome, and Edge to no avail. The Azure environment is pretty basic with no specific policies for anything so I'm not sure why it's saying this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons why you are getting this validation failure.

These are:

- Programmatic deployment for the Marketplace is not configured.
- Undefined task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
- Offer with PublisherId, and OfferId is not found. Doesn't exist anymore. As example, publisher revoked it.
- Marketplace purchase is not enabled.
- Unknown payment instrument(s) is unsupported for offer with OfferId, PlanId.
- Organization is in deleted state.
- etc.

Based on your failure details "*is not available to you for deployment per the policy set by your IT Admin."*, it seems your subscription is not registered and approved to deploy this specific image.

I'd recommend to do the next steps to resolve the issue:

Go to https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/marketplace/manage-private-azure-marketplace-powershell#add-an-offer-to-a-private-marketplace

1. Click on try me button next to Add an Offer the private marketplace.
2. Login to the relevant tenant.
3. Use PowerShell and run the commands:

   ```
     (a) Install-Module -Name Az.Marketplace 
     (b) Get-AzMarketplacePrivateStore - to get the privateStore Id
     (c) use the private store id from step b

    `$Params = @{
    privateStoreId = 'PrivateStoreId'
    offerId = 'paloaltonetworks.vmseries-flex'
    SpecificPlanIdsLimitation = @('byol')
    }
    Set-AzMarketplacePrivateStoreOffer @Params`
   ```

I look forward to your response. Please let me know if you have any questions.